# VBA code to click on Excel icon from a webpage

Tags: html, excel, vba, web, web-scraping

I am trying to automate the click on Excel icon action to download Excel data using VBA from the following link [Financial Statement of a Firm](http://finance.tvsi.com.vn/Enterprises/FinancialStatements?symbol=AAA)

The below is a html code for that Excel icon

```html
<div class="fri nav-item-right">
           <a onclick="changPeriod(2);" class="red" id="hang_quy" style="cursor:pointer;">Hàng quý</a>"|"
           <a onclick="changPeriod(1);" id="hang_nam" style="cursor:pointer;" class="">Hàng năm</a>
           <span class="curp"><img src="/images/icon-excel.jpg" alt="#" id="divPoints"></span>
 </div>
```

The below VBA code intends to trigger the Excel icon clicking action.

```
    URL = "http://finance.tvsi.com.vn/Enterprises/FinancialStatements?symbol=AAA" ' & Range("TickerName")
Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ThisWorkbook.Activate
objIE.Visible = True
objIE.navigate URL

Do While objIE.Busy
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop

Set HTMLDoc = objIE.document
Set oHTML_Elements = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("fri nav-item-right")

    For Each oHTML_Element In oHTML_Elements
        For Each oHTML_Element_Li In oHTML_Element.getElementsByTagName("span")
            oHTML_Element_Li.Children(0).Click
        Next
    Next

    Do While objIE.Busy
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop

     objIE.Quit
```

What happened was the Web Element Tag Name "a" got clicked and not the Excel icon which belong to the Tag Name span.

What did I do wrong from the above code? and if possible please let me know your thoughts on getting this Excel icon Clicked.

Thank you for reading this post and I am looking forward to receiving your suggestion.

Best regards

BK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of the efficient ways how you can download the excel file from that site. When you execute the following macro, you should get the file downloaded in the blink of an eye. You can format the cells later like the way you want.

Btw, the downloaded excel file comes up with an warning as soon as you open it, no matter whether you download the file manually or using the script. However, you can ignore that warning and open the file without having any issue.

```
Sub DownloadExcel()
    Const URL$ = "http://finance.tvsi.com.vn/Enterprises/BangCanDoiKeToan?"
    Dim aBody As Variant, sPath$, params$

    params = "symbol=AAA&YearView=2021&period=2&donvi=1000000"
    
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", URL & params, False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.128 Safari/537.36"
        .send
        aBody = .responseBody
        sPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "output.xls"
    End With
    
    With CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        .Type = 1
        .Open
        .write aBody
        .SaveToFile sPath, 2
        .Close
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello SIM, thank you very much for your quick response on my post. The code rocks like a charm and I am able to match tickers with the sectors or industry they belong to to download their data. Data on the other tab of the page is also easily be downloaded with a small modification on the URL$.  Again, very much appreciate your help on this.

Comment: I am trying to mimic your solution for the download excel icon in [link] (http://finance.tvsi.com.vn/Enterprises/HistoricalQuotesCompany?symbol=AAA) [/link] but did not seem to know the URL and Params strings. Would you please help? Thank you in advance

Comment: I suggest you to create a new post and drop here a link. I'll try to solve your current issue you are having. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you SIM for your willingness. New post is in this link [link] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68520103/vba-code-to-click-on-excel-icon-from-a-webpage-part-2[/link] and I am looking forward to hearing back from you. Thank you!

Comment: You have got an excellent solution already in your linked post.

Comment: Very much appreciate your initiation of the first solution that leads to the second one. Thank you again my friends and truly respect your dedication to the network and forum. I have a question to you. Where should I start if I want to learn more on the approach you used here? please share with me links to resources and tools that I need to up my current level on web data scrapping. Again, Than you very much my Man SIM

Comment: It's difficult to recommend a single source where you can get solutions to many types of problems. However, you can go through different solutions provided by [QHarr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6241235/qharr).